# Python file does not recognise library installed in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

**Explanation**

I had a previous post but I deleted it due to it being meandering and coming to the wrong conclusions.

The command I'm running below doesn't make sense on its own, but it's the file that is ultimately causing problems when other scripts I have run this file down the code path.

I have Python 3.5.1 installed, with `PIP` and `virtualenv`.

If I activate my virtual environment and run `pip list` I get the following.

```
future (0.16.0)
generateDS (2.20a0)
lxml (3.6.4)
mysql-connector (2.1.4)
pefile (2016.3.28)
pip (9.0.1)
PyInstaller (3.2)
pypiwin32 (219)
pypyodbc (1.3.3)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
setuptools (38.5.1)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Now if I run `virtualenv_foobar_20180214093433\Scripts\process_includes.py`.

It immediately throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\site\Python\FooBar\virtualenv_foobar_20180214093433\Scripts\process_includes.py", line 28, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

The relevant code in that file is this.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from lxml import etree

try:
    from gds_inner_name_map import Inner_name_map
except ImportError:
    Inner_name_map = None
```

**Question**

Why is this happening? I've activated the virtual environment, and pip lists the library that it is looking for.

**Extra Information**

I have Python 2 and 3 installed, neither are in Windows Path by default.

Placing `print(platform.python_version())` *inside* `process_includes.py` prints the Python 2 version despite me being inside a virtual environment.

`process_includes.py` has the Python 3 held inside the virtual environment as its shebang.

**Update**

I have no idea why despite neither Python 2 or 3 being in the `PATH`, *and* being inside a Python 3 virtual environment that running the Python file directly would result in it being handled by Python 2.

In the end I updated my scripts to explicitly reference the virtual environment `python.exe` which was a bit of a pain but not the end of the world.

Comment: Does your `process_includes.py` have a shebang line?

Comment: @Jan when I run `where python` I get just `C:\Code\site\Python\FooBar\virtualenv_foobar_20180214093433\Scripts\python.exe`. @Ashish It has a shebang line with the executable I just provided.

Comment: I just put `print(platform.python_version())` inside `process_includes.py` and it prints out `Python 2.7.14`. I have this installed but it's not on `PATH`.

Comment: Please provide the ouput from `python -c "print(__import__('sys').version)"`, you are mostly having version conflicts and the one running is not `Python 3`

Comment: Hi @Jan, printing the version inside process_includes.py prints the Python 2 version despite me being inside a virtual environment. However when I run your command from the command line, it prints information about `3.5.1`. Bizarre.

Comment: Then you may just do `python ...\process_includes.py` from within your virtual environment, so as to ensure the right version is executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while working with my venv. However the error I received was "reportMissingModuleSource" and the code would break during runtime.

Here was my solution:
I've checked what version of python was running on global and ran the same code surprisingly it worked.
Figured it may be some kind of package related issue. I then went back to venv and ran the latest package updates.
I hope this is helpful.